# Invertibility of an operator constructed from the shift operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Consider the Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{Z})\otimes l^2(\mathbb{N})$. Let $p$ be a rank-$1$ projection on $l^2(\mathbb{N})$, and let
$$P=1\otimes p.$$
Let $S$ be the right-shift operator on $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

**Question:** Is the operator $1+P+PS$ unitary (or even invertible)?

*Comment:* So far I've calculated that
$$(1-P+PS)(1-P+PS)^*=(1-P+PS)(1-P+S^*P)=1+(PS(1-P))^*+PS(1-P),$$
but this doesn't seem to reduce to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean $S\otimes 1$ when you write $S$ in your compuations then yes, your operator is a unitary. This follows from the fact that $S$ is a unitary and that the factors commute. In your computation, the second and third terms are
$$
(1\otimes p)(S\otimes 1)(1\otimes (1-p))=S\otimes p(1-p)=0
$$
and its adjoint. So
$$
(1-P+PS)(1-P+PS)^*=1.
$$
On the other side,
$$
(1-P+PS)^*(1-P+PS)=1-P+S^*PS=1-P+PS^*S=1.
$$